# How to find consecutive numbers in a python list?

Tags: python

I'm starting programming in python, now dedicating myself to lists. Is there any possibility of finding sequences with parameters in python lists?
My example:
Find sequences of odd numbers greater than 0, Find the longest one and do sum; if There are two sequences with the same  length, output will be the one which sum is greater.
Then print length of sequence and sum.

Example:

```
Input: - 5 0 10 13 2 4 6 5 - 13 1 2 4 5 8 10 12
Output:
3
30 

(sequence 8, 10, 12)
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using `8, 10, 12` as a sequence if you only want sequences of odd numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

Start by initializing a list with the first element of your original list `l`:

```
longest = []
current_longest = []
```

Then create a for loop that will scan everything in your original list:

```
for el in l:
```

Then check if it adds anything to your original list or not:

```
    if ! current_longest and el % 2 == 0:
        current_longest = [el]
    elif el % 2 == 0 and el == longest[-1] + 2:
        current_longest.append(el)
    else:
        if len(current_longest) > longest or sum(longest) < sum(current_longest):
            longest = current_longest

        current_longest = []
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
def ranges(lst):
   beg = 0
   for idx, elem in enumerate(lst):
     # find the first even number
     if elem % 2 == 0:
       # yield the range of odd numbers
       yield (beg, idx)
       # set a new begin
       beg = idx + 1
   else:
     # the last range
     yield (beg, len(lst))

def rngLen(rng):
    # a length of a range
    return rng[1] - rng[0]

def findSum(lst):
    rngs = list(ranges(lst))
    # find the maximum range
    max_range = max(map(rngLen, rngs))
    # get all the ranges with the length = max_range
    all_max_ranges = filter(lambda rg: rngLen(rg) == max_range, rngs)
    # get the sums of all the max ranges
    all_sums = map(lambda rg: sum(lst[rg[0]: rg[1]]), all_max_ranges)
    # return the max len and sum
    return max_range, max(all_sums)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description says odd sequences but your results show even sequences so here is how it would be done for even sequences, using `enumerate` and `iter` w/ `next`

```
lst = [-5, 0, 10, 13, 2, 4, 6, 5, -13, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12]

res = []
for i, v  in enumerate(lst):
    a = iter(lst[i:])
    b = next(a)
    l = []
    while not b % 2:
        l.append(b)
        try:
            b = next(a)
        except StopIteration:
            break
    if l:
        res.append(l)

print(sorted(res, key=lambda x: (len(x),sum(x)), reverse = True)[0])
# [8, 10, 12]
```